# Creating BOT on Discord to receive and send messages in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

all good?

I created a BOT on Discord and a bot.js that listened to what was sent to the BOT on Discord and sent it to me at a specific Endpoint.

However, only messages on other channels arrive at the Endpoint when the BOT is mentioned. The behavior I want is to send it to the Endpoint when the BOT receives a message in the DM.

My code is like this:

```js
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js');
const axios = require('axios');
const client = new Client({
  intents: [
    GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
    GatewayIntentBits.DirectMessages,
    GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent,
  ],
});

const YOUR_BOT_TOKEN = 'tokenx';
const YOUR_ENDPOINT = 'https://endpointlambda';

client.once('ready', () => {
  console.log('Bot is online!');
});

client.on('messageCreate', async (message) => {
  if (message.author.bot) return; // Ignore messages from     other bots to avoid Loops

  axios
    .post(YOUR_ENDPOINT, {
      content: message.content,
      author: message.author.username,
      id: message.author.id,
    })
    .then((response) => {
      console.log('Message sent to endpoint:', message.content);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error('Error sending message to endpoint:', error);
    });
});

client.login(YOUR_BOT_TOKEN);
```

Can you help me understand what I can do to make it work as expected?

I would like the BOT to receive the user's message, get all the content, including information from the user who sent it to an endpoint. However, data is only being sent when the BOT is mentioned in a Channel, it needed to be sent to the Endpoint when there is a direct message

Comment: Are you sure you fully enabled message intents? The fact that it's only working when the bot is mentioned might indicate an issue related to that.

Answer (score 1):

There are two things you need to do.

First off, your bot does not have the proper permissions to view DMs. To fix this, first include `Partials` when pulling from `discord.js`.

```js
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits, Partials } = require('discord.js');
```

Next, you need to add `Partials.Channel` to the partials section when defining your client. For example:

```js
const client = new Client({
  intents: [
    GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
    GatewayIntentBits.DirectMessages,
    GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent,
  ],
  partials: [
    Partials.Channel
  ]
});
```

After updating this, your bot should be able to receive DMs. To filter out any guild messages, you can add this line under the `messageCreate` event:

```js
  if (message.guild !== null) return;
```

Comment: Describing the partial as a "missing permission" seems inaccurate. For reference, info about the Partial Structures are [here](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/partials.html#enabling-partials). The DM channel is unable to be fully constructed when a message is created since the DM channel is not cached, so the DM message event won't be emitted unless you enable partial channels.